# How to Stop a Timer Task in java

Tags: java, timer

I am building an client program which scan Wi-FI signal every 3 seconds .
I need to collect 41 readings, which means this process will takes around 2 minutes. I need help to stop the timer task after it has completed taking all the reading required (41 readings).

Here is part my my coding:

```
System.out.print("Location Input ( Grid): ");
location=kbline.readLine();
System.out.print("Numbers of Data collect :");
dataString=kbline.readLine();
dataNum=Integer.parseInt(dataString);}
catch(IOException ex5)
{
    System.err.println(ex5);
}

Timer timer= new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new scanTask(location), 0, 3*1000);

//How to cancel the scanTask after taking readings of dataNum
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

Comment: Why don't you use a counter and test it against an upper limit (41 in your case), instead of using a timer?

Comment: thanks for suggestion!